# ZOIB package syntax, one response variable and one fixed variable - r

Tags: r, syntax

I believe I am having a syntax issue within the zoib r package. I am trying to model how a one-inflated proportional response variable (proportion eggs fertilized) changes with lineage male values (also proportional). I do not have any other fixed or random effects. I have tried many different syntax styles, but get the same two errors as below.

````
```>zoib2 <- zoib(prop_Eggs_Fertilized ~ LineageMale | LineageMale, data= subset(Fish_Totals, Laid_Eggs == "Y"), n.response=1, joint = FALSE, zero.inflation = FALSE, one.inflation = TRUE, random = 0, EUID= 1:nrow(d), link.mu = "cloglog", link.x0 = "cloglog", link.x1 = "cloglog")```
````

> > [1] "***************************************************************************" [1] "* List of parameter for which the posterior samples are generated
> > *" [1] "* b: regression coeff in the linear predictor for the mean of beta dist'n *" [1] "* d: regression coeff in the linear predictor for
> > the sum of the two      *" [1] "*    shape parameters in the beta
> > distribution                            *" [1] "* b0: regression coeff
> > in the linear predictor for Prob(y=0)              *" [1] "* b1:
> > regression coeff in the linear predictor for Prob(y=1)              *"
> > [1]
> > "***************************************************************************" Error in fixed1(y[, i], n, xmu.1, p.xmu, xsum.1, p.xsum, x1.1, p.x1,
> > prior1[,  :    object 'x1.1' not found

OR

````
```> zoib2 <- zoib(prop_Eggs_Fertilized ~ LineageMale + 1, data= subset(Fish_Totals, Laid_Eggs == "Y"), n.response=1, joint = FALSE, zero.inflation = FALSE, one.inflation = TRUE, random = 0, EUID= 1:nrow(d), link.mu = "cloglog", link.x0 = "cloglog", link.x1 = "cloglog")```
````

> > Error in zoib(prop_Eggs_Fertilized ~ LineageMale + 1, data = subset(Fish_Totals,  :    please re-specify the model In addition:
> > Warning messages: 1: In zoib(prop_Eggs_Fertilized ~ LineageMale + 1,
> > data = subset(Fish_Totals,  :   The right side of the model should
> > have at least two parts; 2: In zoib(prop_Eggs_Fertilized ~ LineageMale
>
> - 1, data = subset(Fish_Totals,  :   or two link functions, one for the mean of beta distribution 3: In zoib(prop_Eggs_Fertilized ~
>   LineageMale + 1, data = subset(Fish_Totals,  :   alpha/(alpha+beta)
>   and one for the sum (alpha+beta)

TIA for your help.